# Trying with JavaScript to achieve it but something seems to be wrong with the script

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, click

The goal is to make the button turn off if pressed 10 times in less than 1 minute but keep counting if not pressed 10 times in 1 minute? so only disables when pressed 10 times in less than 1 minute. You can click nine times in a minute but nothing happens but the tenth time the button turns off, but if the minute has passed you can keep clicking but always for a maximum ten times and the counter does not reset but continues to increase in number.

```js
let accCounter = 0;
let totalCount = 0;

document.getElementById('totalCounter').innerText = totalCount;

document.getElementById('clap').onclick = function() {
    const clap = document.getElementById('clap');
    const clickCounter = document.getElementById("clicker");
    upClickCounter();

    function upClickCounter() {
      const clickCounter = document.getElementById("clicker");
      const totalClickCounter = document.getElementById('totalCounter');


      accCounter++;
      clickCounter.children[0].innerText = '+' + accCounter;
      totalClickCounter.innerText = totalCount + accCounter;

}
}
      var endCount = 5; // 5 for testing - this would be 10
      var interval = 5000 // 5s for testing, 1 min= 1000 * 60;
      var clicks = [];
      var totalClicks = 0;

      $("#btn").click(function() {
        clicks.push(Date.now());
        totalClicks++;
        checkIt();

      })

      function checkIt() {
        //if (clicks.length < endCount) return;

        while (clicks.length && (Date.now() - clicks[0]) > interval) {
          console.log("removing: " + ((Date.now() - clicks[0]) / 1000))
          clicks.shift();
        }

        if (clicks.length < endCount) return;

        $("#btn")[0].disabled = true;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clap" class="clap-container"></button>
<div id="totalCounter" class="total-counter"></div>
<div id="clicker" class="click-counter"></div>
```

Comment: I would use Rxjs

Comment: this isn't clear:  You can click nine times in a minute but nothing happens but the tenth time the button turns off, but if the minute has passed you can keep clicking but always for a maximum ten times and the counter does not reset but continues to increase in number.

Comment: YES DCR this is what i am trying to achieve, in one minute for example the button can be pressed only max 10 times but if i click 9 times and wait 1 minutes than i can continue to click with the counter increasing in number and not reset after one minute same goes for the next minutes .

Comment: The  button only disable when the clicks are to much in one minutes 
 otherwise nothig happens!